# WinJS: Remove tooltip from Slider

Tags: winjs

How can i remove the tooltip from a Slider control (input[range]) in WinJS?

[image: Tooltip]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the `::-ms-tooltip` pseudo element and set `display:` to `none;`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465805.aspx

```css
input[type=range]::-ms-tooltip {
    display: none;
}
```