# Input range type doesn't work correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a range slider but it doesn't work correctly in Internet Explorer.

```
<input id="slider-customer-type" type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" />
```

When I move it in IE, it shows me the value (0-1) depending the position.

How can I hide the values showing me?

Firefox works correctly and doesn't show me the values, this only happens with IE.

[image: Slider image]

Answer (score 2):

See this answer - [Hide or change the value label for a range input in IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487550/hide-or-change-the-value-label-for-a-range-input-in-ie10/15487800#15487800)

Essentially, put

```
input::-ms-tooltip {
    display: none;
}
```

in your CSS.

Comment: thanks, it works good

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465805.aspx

Example CSS:

```
#slider-customer-type::-ms-tooltip {
    display: none;
}
```

...or as @romellem suggested;  `input::-ms-tooltip { display: none; }` which will disable the tooltip from every `<input>` you might have.